# Typescript type narrowing not working when using generic type

Tags: typescript

Below code type narrowing seems not working in Typescript version 3.8 (Angular 9 frontend)
I try to experiment a bit with no progress.

- I think this is not related to I use enum wrongly, but it involves some complexity about extending generic in TypeScript.
- Maybe if I want to make the code narrowing works but I use the wrong way to define the interface?

Anyone can provide me a hint?

[See Below or StackBkitz Code To Show My Situation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-j2wkzx)

```
export enum DetailType {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B',
  C = 'C',
}

interface D1 {
  type: DetailType.A;
}

interface D2 {
  type: DetailType.B;
}

interface D3 {
  type: DetailType.C;
}

type Detail = D1 | D2 | D3;


type SystemFinding<detailType extends Detail> = {
  detail: detailType;
};

interface Finding<detailType extends Detail> extends SystemFinding<detailType> {
  findingUid?: string;
}


type FindingSummary<T extends Detail> = {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: Finding<T>;
};


function runA(st: FindingSummary<D1>) {
  console.log(st);
}

function runB(st: FindingSummary<D2>) {
  console.log(st);
}

function runC(st: FindingSummary<D3>) {
  console.log(st);
}

function runTool(findingSummary: FindingSummary<Detail>) {
  switch (findingSummary.prop2.detail.type) {
    case DetailType.A:
      findingSummary; // type is findingSummary: FindingSummary<Detail>, type narrowing isn't working?
      runA(findingSummary);
      break;
    case DetailType.C:
      findingSummary;
      runB(findingSummary);
      break;
    case DetailType.C:
      findingSummary;
      runB(findingSummary);
      break;
    default:
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have to use type casting. But I hope I don't need to do that.

```
function runTool(findingSummary: findingSummary<Detail>) {
  switch (findingSummary.prop2.detail.type) {
    case DetailType.A:
      const a1: findingSummary<D1> = <findingSummary<D1>>findingSummary;
      runA(a1);
      break;
    case DetailType.B:
      const a2: findingSummary<D2> = <findingSummary<D2>>findingSummary; 
      runB(a2);
      break;
    case DetailType.C:
      const a3: findingSummary<D3> = <findingSummary<D3>>findingSummary; 
      runC(a3);
      break;
    default:
  }
}
```